# Why does C++ read values wrong from txt files?

Tags: c++, numbers

I have made a program that reads value from txt file "database.txt", but output is wrong when the number is three digit

```
ifstream myfile("database.txt");
int broj_rijeci = 0;
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while (getline(myfile, line))
    {
        if (line.at(0) == '[')
        {
            int i = line.length() - 2;
            int brojac = 0;
            system("pause");
            while (line.at(i) != line.at(0))
            {
                input = line.at(i);
                ascii_convert(input);
                broj_rijeci = broj_rijeci + input * pow(10, brojac);
                i--;
                brojac++;
            }
        }
    }
    myfile.close();
}
else cout << "Unable to open file";
```

and my database looks like this:

```
[311]
```

output is "310"

Comment: Nice to see a question about stream io that doesn't attempt to use `eof()` ;).

Comment: Did you step through the code in your debugger and look at the variable assignments in the loop?

Comment: What does ascii_convert do?

Comment: ... and `input` was which type again? Please post (real) compilable code at least.

Comment: by the way, I hope you know that you are overcomplicating a simple task.

Comment: How is your "ascii_convert()" function implemented? When I use "input -= 48;" instead, everything works fine for me (see http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a79c941ba5d567e9). IF you use C++11, have a look at "std::stoi" → http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

Comment: I don't think that `while (line.at(i) != line.at(0))` is correct, since `'[' != ']'`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you haven't provided the implementation of `ascii_convert` it's difficult to tell if the problem is there or elsewhere. However you can greatly simplify the process and eliminate the need for your own conversion routines by using `std::stringstream`.

```
#include <sstream>

std::ifstream myfile("database.txt");
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(myfile, line))
    {
        if (line.size() > 1 && line[0] == '[' && line[line.size() - 1] == ']')
        {
            int value;
            if(std::istringstream(line.substr(1, line.size() - 2)) >> value)
            {
                // Conversion was a success ... do something with "value"
            }
            else
            {
                // Conversion failed. Handle error condition.
            }
        }
    }
    myfile.close();
}
else std::cout << "Unable to open file";
```

Answer (score 0):

Patching up your code to be a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) shows the expected result:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <sstream>
 #include <string>
 #include <math.h>

 int main()
 {
     std::istringstream myfile("[311]");
     int broj_rijeci = 0;
     for (std::string line; std::getline(myfile, line); )
     {
         if (2 < line.size() && line.at(0) == '[')
         {
             int i = line.length() - 2;
             int brojac = 0;
             while (line[i] != line[0])
             {
                 char input = line[i];
                 input -= '0';
                 broj_rijeci = broj_rijeci + input * pow(10, brojac);
                 i--;
                 brojac++;
             }
         }
     }
     std::cout << "result=" << broj_rijeci << '\n';
 }
```

That said, this code is probably a lot slower than it needs to be. For example, computing the power even of an integer takes a couple of operations in each iteration while there is really just one multiplication needed:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream in("[311]");
    for (std::string line; std::getline(in, line); ) {
        if (2 < line.size() && line.front() == '[' && line.back() == ']') {
            int result(0);
            for (std::string::const_iterator it(line.begin() + 1), end(line.end());
                 std::isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(*it)); ++it) {
                result = result * 10 + *it - '0';
            }
            std::cout << "result=" << result << '\n';
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "ERROR: unexpected format on line '" << line << "'\n";
        }
    }
}
```